# Put an item in Amazon DynamoDB with AWS SDK CPP using as input the item in JSON format

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-cpp

Is there any easy way to put an item in *Amazon DynamoDB* with *AWS SDK CPP* using as input the item in *JSON* format? Something like

```
Aws::DynamoDB::Model::PutItemRequest request;
request.SetTableName(table);
request.FunctionThatSetsAllAttributesParsingAJsonString(json_string);
```

Or is it always necessary to set each attribute and its type?

```
Aws::DynamoDB::Model::PutItemRequest request;
request.SetTableName(table);
Aws::DynamoDB::Model::AttributeValue val1;
val1.SetS(str);
request.AddItem(key, val1);
Aws::DynamoDB::Model::AttributeValue val2;
...
```

Comment: I do not believe there is an interface that accepts a JSON string but you could iterate over the keys of the JSON, populate an AttributeValue, and add that to the PutItemRequest in a somewhat generic fashion. Presumably you really want/need to use C++ but, if not, there are much easier ways to do this in other languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the *JSON* object follows *Amazon DynamoDB JSON* format, you can easily convert it into an *Aws::Map<Aws::String, Aws::DynamoDB::Model::AttributeValue>* object. For instance, for a *Jsoncpp* *Json::Value* object:

```
Aws::Map<Aws::String, Aws::DynamoDB::Model::AttributeValue> json2atts(const Json::Value& json) {
    try {
        Aws::Map<Aws::String, Aws::DynamoDB::Model::AttributeValue> amap;
        Aws::Utils::Json::JsonValue jval(Json::FastWriter().write(json));
        if (!jval.WasParseSuccessful()) {
            throw exception("Failed to parse input JSON");
        };
        Aws::Utils::Json::JsonView jview = jval.View();
        Aws::Map<Aws::String, Aws::Utils::Json::JsonView> jmap = jview.GetAllObjects();
        for(auto& i : jmap) {
            amap[i.first] = i.second.AsObject();
        };
        return amap;
    }
    catch (std::exception &e) { 
       ...
    };
};
```

Then, to put the *Aws::Map<Aws::String, Aws::DynamoDB::Model::AttributeValue>* object:

```
Aws::DynamoDB::Model::PutItemRequest request;
request.SetTableName(table);
request.SetItem(amap);
```